# Getting username of a user for REST API in django

Tags: python, django, rest

I am making rest api for one of my models

```
class BongWallet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

when I get the user field through rest serializer I get the userURL. So my question is how to create a field for username in this model so that I can return username rather than userURL in REST

```
user.username
```

gives no results

Comment: Could you show the code you're using right now ?

Comment: must be a configuration issue in your serializer, user.username would normally work

Comment: Yeah I used hyperlinkmodelserializer , changed to model serializer - everything works fine now